# get/edit code of function with Ipython

Tags: ipython

when you enter function??, besides the info you get the source code of the function if there is available.
Is there a way of?:

1) get the code as str object
2) edit in place similar to %load

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the module and function names as "module" and "function" string variables, then

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, getsource

internal_module = __import__(module)
internal_functions = dict(getmembers(internal_module, isfunction))
source_code = getsource(internal_functions[function])
```

will give you a dictionary (internal_functions) containing all functions in the module and a string (source_code) containing the source of that specific function.

You would then have to manipulate the string in order to edit the function, I think.